# How to achieve silent printing using javascript? Do not want to show print preview

Tags: javascript

```
var content = document.getElementById("container");
var pri = document.getElementById("contentstoprint").contentWindow;
pri.document.open();
pri.document.write(content.innerHTML);
pri.document.close();
pri.focus();
pri.print();
```

using this to print a div elements, but I need to print it in background process, not after showing preview and clicking on Print button of preview pane. I am trying to this with Reactjs along with Redux.

Comment: What is silent printing? Why do you need this?

Comment: This is not related to ReactJS at all

Comment: Yes, this not related to react, since I was trying to do this in a reactJS project, so tagged.

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible. Browsers require that users confirm they really want to print.

If that wasn't the case then it would be trivial to include a web page which did something like `setInterval(print, 1000);` and then wasted a large quantity of ink and paper. (Imagine an office environment where the printer is at the other end of the room to the user and is shared between lots of people)).

Answer (score 0):

You need a browser specific extension to achieve silent printing.  For Firefox, you can use JS Print Setup: https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/

This way you can setup the printer and print directly from Javascript.

Comment: Thanks Marc, actually I was looking for some solution where I could do something using javascript or any existing node based package/project..

Comment: Nope, I had to drop the idea.